# Create React App: how to get final port dev-server running on

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

From https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/advanced-configuration you can provide your own script to `BROWSER` environment variable.

On this script, I want to open link to some other page, with a query parameter to redirect to port the dev-server is running on localhost.

Even if I do `BROWSER=open.js PORT=4000 npm run start`, port `4000` may be taken, which is what `choosePort` from https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/scripts/start.js#L87 does; it finds the first port available around the provided port.

My question is this: given my `open.js`, how can I find the actual PORT the dev-server is running on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that that the `process.argv` does in fact contain the URL (with port) of your dev-server.

```
console.log(process.argv)
```

Provides:

```
[ '/usr/local/bin/node',
  '/path/to/my/custom/openBrowser.js',
  'http://localhost:3000/' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

To get current port you can use:

```
console.log(window.location.port)
```

`window.location` also provides more useful information.

Comment: Not going to work - I'm asking how to get the port on the server, not the browser.